# Prevent page scroll when focusing input located inside of a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

On my website I have a drawer (a modal) containing form with inputs inside. And whenever user clicks on inputs browser tries to center them, but since a drawer is absolutely positioned, it scrolls underlying content instead and absolutely positioned element jumps. This thing happens on iOS devices, both chrome and safari.

Is there a way to fix it? Everything I found online so far doesn't work.

Here is a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/small-water-v1m1tq

And here is a gif

[image: bug recording]

Actually this is an old problem that I can't fix for a long time, but recently I noticed that notion has such modals, and they somehow managed to fix this issue.

[image: notion recording]

This modal doesn't have top margin, but it doesn't matter.
Changed the layout to be like theirs, but nothing helps. Here is a link: https://leather-colby-f69.notion.site/Job-Board-4323320545bb4484bfc1008cff34cebd

Comment: One possible solution I could think of is adding ```document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"``` to your button, but this only works as a workaround though.

Comment: @AnthonyDev220 Yes, it works, but you need to manually restore the scroll position. Notion does it in some other way.

Comment: You can try changing your calculation units of **vh** instaed of **%**  in the **calc()** function. From `height: calc(100% - 64px);` to `height: calc(100vh - 64px);`. I can check it, I don't use Mac.

Comment: @Anton Nope, didn’t work. :( Also tried ‘width: 100vw; height: 100vh’ (like notion), doesn’t work neither.

Comment: For those willing to help but not having a Mac: Mac is not necessary, in fact, issue can’t be reproduced on Mac because it only happens on iPhone. Cosesandbox has  a “Open in new window” button. You have to copy this link and open it on the iPhone.

Comment: @bapafes482 Try this CSS property [overscroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior)

Comment: @Anton Unfortunately this property is not supported on mobile safari yet. But yes, it looks promising. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my testing it would seem the flickering is caused by Safari resizing the window before computing the layout again. My guess is some combination of the fixed layout containing the input and some obscure bug.

From your code I simply added

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and the issues went away. I suspect by making the html and body elements positioned `relative`  (and not `static` which is default) it would correctly recomputed the layout when Safari was doing its resize shenanigans on keyboard show/hide. These are just guesses though based on observation.

This type of style is also similar to what you see in css reset sheets. The reason they do it might be a clue to this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should use body-scroll-lock package like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { disableBodyScroll, enableBodyScroll } from 'body-scroll-lock';

export default function App() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const rows = new Array(80).fill();

  useEffect(() => {
    modalVisible ? disableBodyScroll(document) : enableBodyScroll(document)
  }, [modalVisible]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="lorem">
        {rows.map((_, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{index}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setModalVisible(true)}
        style={{ "font-size": "16px" }}
      >
        open drawer
      </button>
      {modalVisible && (
        <div className="drawer-root">
          <div
            className="drawer-mask"
            style={{
              position: "fixed",
              height: "100%",
              "background-color": "#00000073",
              inset: "0"
            }}
          />
          <div
            className="drawer"
            style={{
              "box-sizing": "border-box",
              position: "fixed",
              bottom: "0",
              height: "calc(100% - 64px)",
              width: "100%",
              background: "white",
              padding: "16px",
              display: "flex",
              "flex-direction": "column",
              "justify-content": "space-between"
            }}
          >
            <input placeholder="Search..." style={{ "font-size": "16px" }} />
            <button
              onClick={() => setModalVisible(false)}
              style={{ "font-size": "16px" }}
            >
              close drawer
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but I wrote that I need a solution without overflow: hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can disable scrolling and temporarily push the page off the top of the screen by giving it a negative `top` value equal to the scroll offset. Then when hiding the modal you scroll back to the original value with JS. As long as there's no smooth scrolling set through CSS, this should happen instantaneous.

```
let scrollPosition;

const freezeScroll = () => {
  scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  document.body.style.top = `-${scrollPosition}px`;
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
};

const restoreScroll = () => {
  if (scrollPosition === null) {
      // Nothing to do as scroll was never frozen.
      return;
  }
  document.body.style.top = 0;
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  window.scrollTo({
    top: scrollPosition,
    behavior: 'auto'
  });
};

function App() {
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    // ...

    useEffect(() => {
        modalVisible ? freezeScroll() : restoreScroll();
    }, [modalVisible]);
    
    // ...
}
```

I got this working for your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-edison-h0bwnm?file=/src/App.js

Note that because CSS properties were added with dashes and not camel case, the style looks quite broken, but it's enough to see the solution working. It should play well with the CSS if you restore it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but I wrote that I need a solution without overflow: hidden

Comment: Can you explain why it can't have `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: For three reasons. First and foremost: Because overflow: hidden doesn't work. Here is your example with the corrected layout. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-driscoll-g1d6j0 Open it on your iPhone. The screen twitches, body scrolls.  The scroll position restores after modal is closed, but this is not enough, I need the screen not to twitch. The second: Even if it worked, In my project there are cases where the modal opens on top of the modal. And managing scroll postion becomes a hell I dont want to deal with.Third: Somehow notion.so  managed to fix these modals without using overflow: hidden.

Comment: @bapafes482 The codesandbox you posted also has code from the other answer, and it seems to miss all CSS, so it's not working at all for me. Some of the properties passed to React are still written the wrong way (`"flex-direction"` instead of `flexDirection`), so have no effect. Can you please fix this so I can have a proper look at it? I'm using free Browserstack so I'm pretty limited in the amount of time I can check on iPhone.

Comment: Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-villani-weqo2u

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not use overflow: hidden, you can probably change the display property to none.
Basically, when you will click the button, it will appear the modal full screen, so you don't have to see the div on the back.

You can see the results here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigorous-dream-v22o6b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Simply, you have to wrap the div and the button that scrolls, and every time you click the button you change the display property of that wrapper to none and vice-versa when you close the modal.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const rows = new Array(80).fill();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper"> //this is the wrapper
        <div className="lorem">
           {rows.map((_, index) => (
              <div key={index}>{index}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
              document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display = "none";  //here you change the property of the wrapper to none
          }}
         style={{ "font-size": "16px" }}
         >
         open drawer
         </button>
     </div>
  {modalVisible && (
    <div className="drawer-root">
      <div
        className="drawer-mask"
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          height: "100%",
          "background-color": "#00000073",
          inset: "0"
        }}
      />
      <div
        className="drawer"
        style={{
          "box-sizing": "border-box",
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: "0",
          height: "calc(100% - 64px)",
          width: "100%",
          background: "white",
          padding: "16px",
          display: "flex",
          "flex-direction": "column",
          "justify-content": "space-between"
        }}
      >
        <input placeholder="Search..." style={{ "font-size": "16px" }} />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setModalVisible(false);
            document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display =
              "block"; //here you set again the display property to block
          }}
          style={{ "font-size": "16px" }}
        >
          close drawer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple in my opinion.
I have a custom hook `usePreventScroll` that can be expanded to a reusable wrap component something like `<PreventScroll></PreventScroll>` for components such as Modal, custom Dialog Box, Context Menu etc.

Doing quick search I came across this [article][1]
from useHooks that explains it better and has good example.

Here's the code for quick reference though

```
function useLockBodyScroll() {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Get original body overflow
    const originalStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).overflow;
   
    // Prevent scrolling on mount
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    // Re-enable scrolling when component unmounts
    return () => (document.body.style.overflow = originalStyle);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures effect is only run on mount and unmount
}
```

Another thing I noticed when working was to pass a variable to enable this behavior conditionally so something like

```
export function useLockBodyScroll(enable) {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Get original body overflow
    const originalStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).overflow
    // Prevent scrolling on mount
    if (enable) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    }
    // Re-enable scrolling when component unmounts
    return () => (document.body.style.overflow = originalStyle)
  }, []) // Empty array ensures effect is only run on mount and unmount
}
```

A reusable wrapper component would look/work something like

```
const PreventScrollWrap = (children) => {
    useLockBodyScroll()
    return <>{children}</>
}


  [1]: https://usehooks.com/useLockBodyScroll/
```